# Using expand.grid but keeping named character values

Tags: r

I have a nested list with named character vectors, I'm using `expand.grid()` to generate every possible value. This is going well, however I'd like to also keep the named values.

My structure is as follows:

```
a <- list("id1" = c(setNames(1,"Apple"), setNames(2,"Banana")), "id2" = c(setNames(3,"Jam"), setNames(4,"Peanut butter")))

> a
$id1
 Apple Banana 
     1      2 

$id2
          Jam Peanut butter 
            3             4
```

Using `expand.grid()` gives the following:

```
> expand.grid(a)
  id1 id2
1   1   3
2   2   3
3   1   4
4   2   4
```

However, how I'd like it to be is:

```
> a
  id1 id2 id1.name id2.name
1   1   3  Apple    Jam
2   2   3  Banana   Peanut butter
3   1   4  Apple    Jam
4   2   4  Banana   Peanut butter
```

Is there a way to do this? I'm currenly trying to create a lookup table that then matches all values afterwards, but this is also proving difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer depends on the data structure that you provided: a list of named numbers.

```
str(a)
# List of 2
#  $ id1: Named num [1:2] 1 2
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "Apple" "Banana"
#  $ id2: Named num [1:2] 3 4
#  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "Jam" "Peanut butter"
grd <- expand.grid(a)
str(grd)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ id1     : Named num  1 2 1 2
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Apple" "Banana" "Apple" "Banana"
#  $ id2     : Named num  3 3 4 4
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Jam" "Jam" "Peanut butter" "Peanut butter"
#  $ id1.name: chr  "Apple" "Banana" "Apple" "Banana"
#  $ id2.name: chr  "Jam" "Jam" "Peanut butter" "Peanut butter"
#  - attr(*, "out.attrs")=List of 2
#   ..$ dim     : Named int [1:2] 2 2
#   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "id1" "id2"
#   ..$ dimnames:List of 2
#   .. ..$ id1: chr [1:2] "id1=1" "id1=2"
#   .. ..$ id2: chr [1:2] "id2=3" "id2=4"
```

Notice the names are included in the data frame as attributes which makes it simple to get what you want:

```
grd$id1.name <- names(grd$id1)
grd$id2.name <- names(grd$id2)
print(grd, right=FALSE)
#   id1 id2 id1.name id2.name     
# 1 1   3   Apple    Jam          
# 2 2   3   Banana   Jam          
# 3 1   4   Apple    Peanut butter
# 4 2   4   Banana   Peanut butter
```

Comment: That's a smart and concise solution, indeed. It's always a good idea to have a close look at what's in the data.

Comment: Super elegant solution, awesome! My code ended up being:
`a %>%
  map_dfr(function(x) {x <- expand.grid(x)
          x$id1.name <- names(x$id1)
          x$id2.name <- names(x$id2)
          return(x)})`

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`crossing`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/expand.html).

1. Loop over the `list` of named `vector` - [`map`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html)
2. Use [`stack`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/stack) from `base R` to convert the named vector -> two column `ind/values` data.frame
3. Apply `crossing` within [`invoke`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.5/topics/invoke) - similar to `do.call` from `base R`
4. Flatten the `list` columns to create normal columns by calling `data.frame
5. Rename the columns (if needed)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map(a, stack) %>% 
   invoke(crossing, .)%>% 
   invoke(data.frame, .) %>% 
   rename_with(~ str_replace_all(., setNames(c("", ".name"), 
         c("\\.values", "\\.ind"))), everything())
   id1 id1.name id2      id2.name
1   1    Apple   3           Jam
2   1    Apple   4 Peanut butter
3   2   Banana   3           Jam
4   2   Banana   4 Peanut butter
```

---

Or another option is using [`expand_grid`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/expand.html) by looping over the `list` with `imap`, and create the column names with the `names` of the `list` by assignment (`:=`) and finally reorder the columns in `select`

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
imap_dfc(a, ~ expand_grid(!! .y := .x, 
      !! str_c(.y, ".name") := names(.x))) %>%
     select(matches("^id\\d+$"), everything())
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
    id1   id2 id1.name id2.name     
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>        
1     1     3 Apple    Jam          
2     1     3 Banana   Peanut butter
3     2     4 Apple    Jam          
4     2     4 Banana   Peanut butter
```

Comment: Very nifty!  Just curious: is there an equally nifty way to consolidate this `list` of `data.frame`s into a _single_ `data.frame`?  And to make the column names fully extensible, for a list `a` of arbitrary length `n`, such that the result has the column names `id1` | `id2` | ... | `idn` | `id1.name` | `id2.name` | ... | `idn.name`?  Obviously `do.call(dplyr::bind_cols, list_of_dataframes)` would butcher the names...

Comment: Maybe `do.call(bind_cols, mapply(FUN = function(df, pref){setNames(df, paste(pref, c("id", "name")[match(names(df), c("values", "ind"))], sep = "."))}, map(a, stack) %>% invoke(crossing, .), names(a), SIMPLIFY = FALSE))`?  But this is hardly elegant, and I suspect it defeats the purpose of your efficiency in `map(a, stack) %>% invoke(crossing, .)`.

Comment: @Greg sorry greg, I was away.  I think you want to flatten the data, then just add `invoke(data.frame, .)` at the end

Comment: Nice!  Much cleaner with `%>%` than with nested functions...

Comment: @Greg I added another way to correct the names

Comment: :)  Though I do wonder if it wouldn't be simpler to pipe `map(a, stack) %>% invoke(crossing, .) %>% ...`, pipe again to change the names (ie. map `"values"` to `"id"` and `"ind"` to `"name"`) for each `data.frame` in the resulting `list`, and then finally pipe through `... %>% invoke(data.frame, .)`.  By dealing with the name mapping upstream, this would eliminate the need for regex substitution after the fact.

Comment: @Greg that is also possible.  Updatd

Comment: Thanks for humoring me!  I'm curious, though: why not just `map(a, stack) %>% invoke(crossing, .) %>% ... %>% invoke(data.frame, .)`, where `...` contains a better version of `sapply(FUN = setNames, c("id", "name"), simplify = FALSE)`?  No regex required!

Comment: @Greg that also works, but there is a suffix `.id` which could be removed `map(a, stack) %>% 
   invoke(crossing, .)%>% sapply(FUN = setNames, c("", "name"), simplify = FALSE) %>% invoke(data.frame, .)`

Comment: Good catch: _"but there is a suffix `.id` which could be removed"_; I had misread Keipi's output as `id1` **`.id`** | `id2` **`.id`** | `...`, rather than simply  `id1` | `id2` | `...`.  I am indeed surprised to learn that other programmers favor string replacement after the fact, rather than addressing the names upstream, but then again, one might want the result to have an entirely new naming convention anyway, which could be done in one fell swoop by regex at the very end.  **Good to know, and thanks for discussing!**